# Allowing a user to edit a CSV file

Tags: ruby, csv

In Ruby 3.1.2, using this CSV file:

```
make,model,color,doors,email
dodge,charger,black,4,practice1@whatever.com
ford,focus,blue,5,practice2@whatever.com
nissan,350z,black,2,practice3@whatever.com
mazda,miata,white,2,practice4@whatever.com
honda,civid,brown,4,practice5@whatever.com
corvette,stingray,red,2,practice6@whatever.com
ford,fiesta,blue,5,practice7@whatever.com
bmw,m4,black,2,practice8@whatever.com
audi,a5,blue,2,practice9@whatever.com
subaru,brz,black,2,practice10@whatever.com
lexus,rc,black,2,practice11@whatever.com
```

If the user does not enter an email address that is part of the CSV file above or anything that does not equal an email, the program asks the user to enter a valid email until they actually do, and then update the CSV file with the deleted row corresponding to the email. My current code does this but there is no checking if the user enters a valid email address or not and that is the part I am stuck on. This is my code:

```
def delete_from_data
    print "\nTo delete a car, enter the email (this is case sensitive): \n> "
    delete_car = gets.chomp

    #this allows me to delete a certain row based on email
    table = CSV.table("cars.csv")
    table.delete_if do |row|
        row[:email] == delete_car
    end
    File.open("cars.csv", "w") do |f|
        f.write(table.to_csv)
    end

    #this shows the updated student roster after deleting user
    puts "\nThis is the updated roster after deleting: #{delete_car}"
end
```

for example, if the user enters "`practice11@whatever.com`", then that whole row from the CSV file gets deleted. But if a user enters anything else other than a valid email address from the CSV file, it still runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the [documentation of CSV::Table](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Table.html#method-i-delete_if) and notice that it has a `#each` method that allows you to iterate over the rows.  In fact, lots of Ruby container classes have a `#each` method so you will need to get familiar with it if you want to do anything meaningful in Ruby.

Something like this should work:

```
email_found = false
while !email_found
  email = gets.chomp
  table.each do |row|
    if row[:email] == email
      email_found = true 
    end
  end
end
```

Note that this is not meant to be beautiful or optimized code, but simple, beginner-level code.

For extra credit, learn about Ruby's Enumerable module and use `.any?` instead of `.each`.

Comment: after running this with my code it does check if there is an email and doesn't continue if a valid one isn't entered so that part worked, however it does not update the CSV file

Comment: I thought you already knew how to update the CSV.  Use the existing code you have that calls `delete_if`, `write`, and so on.  The code in this answer is just a small fragment of the complete program and of course it doesn't modify anything other than the `email` and `email_found` variables.